# How can I merge duplicate objects with Linq while concatenating a property?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have an object:

```
private class User
    {
        public string fullname { get; set; }
        public string manager { get; set; }
        public string businessunit { get; set; }
        public string employeeid { get; set; }
        public string mainphone { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string street3 { get; set; }
        public string street2 { get; set; }
        public string street1 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string stateorprovince { get; set; }
        public string ziporpostalcode { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public string countryorregion { get; set; }
        public string salesarea { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string companyname { get; set; }
        public string securityroles { get; set; }
        public User()
        {

        }
    }
```

I also have a list of that object:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
```

What I'd like to do is merge all Users in the list with the same **fullname** while concatenating all of their different **securityroles** into the same **securityroles** property.

I was thinking something along the lines of this would work:

```
users = (from user in users
                 group user by user.fullname
                 /*not sure what to put here*/).ToList();
```

Comment: How will you "merge" other properties?  Just concatenate all the string properties? Assume only one has a value?  Assume that they're all the same?

Comment: So if you have two people with the same fullname, you want one object with the securityroles from each concatenated together?  What about the other fields, just disregard entirely?  Which user in the group do you want to take, just the first arbitrarily?

Comment: @DStanley I am merging objects. You could also say I'm merging one of the properties of that object, only one! Due to how I obtained this data, I know that no two users with the same fullname have the same securityroles property.

Comment: @maccettura Taking the first arbitrarily is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you D Stanley and mzaverez. This function works but I might change it since the merge function executes multiple queries:

```
private User Merge(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        User u = new User();
        if (!users.Any())
        {
            return u;
        }
        else
        {
            u.fullname = users.First().fullname;
            u.manager = users.First().manager;
            u.businessunit = users.First().businessunit;
            u.employeeid = users.First().employeeid;
            u.mainphone = users.First().mainphone;
            u.fax = users.First().fax;
            u.mobile = users.First().mobile;
            u.email = users.First().email;
            u.street1 = users.First().street1;
            u.street2 = users.First().street2;
            u.street3 = users.First().street3;
            u.city = users.First().city;
            u.stateorprovince = users.First().stateorprovince;
            u.ziporpostalcode = users.First().ziporpostalcode;
            u.department = users.First().department;
            u.countryorregion = users.First().countryorregion;
            u.salesarea = users.First().salesarea;
            u.title = users.First().title;
            u.username = users.First().username;
            u.companyname = users.First().companyname;
            u.securityroles = string.Join(", ", users.Select(x => x.securityroles));
            return u;
        }
    }
```

That function is called by the very helpful Linq code D Stanley suggested below:

```
users = (from user in users
         group user by user.fullname into g
         select Merge(g)
        ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would write a function that merges a collection of `User`s into one and call that from your query:

```
private User Merge(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    User user = new User();

    if(!users.Any()) return user; // or null, whatever you think is appropriate

    user.fullname = users.First().fullname;
    user.securityroles = string.Join(", ", users.Select(u => u.securityroles));
    // similar rules/queries for other properties.
}
```

Then just call it from the main query:

```
users = (from user in users
         group user by user.fullname into g
         select Merge(g)
        ).ToList();
```

If you don't like having multiple queries in the `Merge` function, then re-write it as a `foreach` loop, or use whatever construct you see fit.

The point is to get something that *works* and defines your rules for "merge" outside of your Linq query, then make it *better*.

Comment: Your code does not compile. "A local variable named 'u' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'u', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: @MichaelDrum Well, maybe rename one of them and it will be fine?

Comment: @Timbo I should have realized that.

Comment: @Timbo I renamed the first `u` to `user` to clear the error.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks I'll mark your answer correct. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

Using [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) answer, I ran the code on online compiler, with some mods. Needs to add the others properties in merge function, like Stanley said.

http://rextester.com/YJV50083

The user list (the 'A,B,C,D,E' are securityroles):

> Users:
>
> Test1 A
>
> Test1 B
>
> Test2 C
>
> Test2 D
>
> Test3 E

After linq:

> New users:
>
> Test1 A, B
>
> Test2 C, D
>
> Test3 E